# Achartengine auto follow - extra space on y axis

Tags: android, diagram, achartengine

I am new to achartengine and I like it. Great job!

I am using a line graph with dynamically added points. If I don't touch it, the auto scale and follow feature works fine. However I'd like to have some extra space on top of the y axis (see screenshot). How can I do that? I don't want the points to touch the upper edge of the diagram.

This is my code:

```
public Linegraph() {
        mDataset.addSeries(dataset);

        renderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.TRIANGLE);
        renderer.setFillPoints(true);

        // enable zoom
        mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        mRenderer.setXTitle("Value #");
        mRenderer.setYTitle("Value");
        mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(25);
        mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(25);
        mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(25);
        mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(25);
        mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
        mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.RED);
        mRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.RED);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        mRenderer.setYAxisMin(-1);
        mRenderer.setXAxisMin(-1);

    }

    public GraphicalView getView(Context context) {
        return ChartFactory.getLineChartView(context, mDataset, mRenderer);
    }

    public void addNewPoint(Point p) {
        dataset.add(p.getX(), p.getY());
    }
```

How can I re-enable the auto follow feature after touching and moving the view manually?

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to always know the data range and set the visible area to something that includes the range and adds a some small space. For instance, if the data ranges between 0 and 100 on X axis and from 5 and 10 on the Y axis, something like this will be good:

```
renderer.setXAxisMin(-0.5);
renderer.setXAxisMax(100.5);
renderer.setXAxisMin(4.75);
renderer.setXAxisMax(10.25);
```

For the second question:

```
renderer.initAxisRange(1);
```

Comment: The first part of the answer works perfectly. There is some extra space and the graph looks much better.
As for the second part: It scales again, but the extra space is missing again. If this could have the effect of the first part (=extra space) I would be totally happy!
Thanks for the fast support!

Without doubt: This library is nice, but a little better JavaDoc would make a lot of questions redundant. The method `initAxisRange()` has no documentation at all. I'm still uncertain about what `setRange()` does in contrary to `setXAxisMin/Max`

Answer (score 0):

As for my understanding to your question you should give pan limits

`mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 60, 120, 60, 60 });`